# Infinite sum evaluation-square root

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, generating-functions

I'm defining the following function $S(x,n)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty i^nx^i$

Just to list the first few,

$S(x,1)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$

$S(x,2)=\frac{x(x+1)}{(1-x)^3}$

$S(x,3)=\frac{x(x^2+4x+1)}{(1-x)^4}$

I tried to evaluate $S(x,\frac{1}{2})$   but am getting no where. I've done the above three examples with algebra. There's probably some function or theorem that can solve this but I have no idea.

I'd like the function S(x,1/2) to be defined for all real value of x except x=1, for that will give the function $\sqrt 1 +\sqrt 2 +\sqrt 3...$ which is divergent

Any advise is appreciated.

P.S. This isn't for paper or assignment so don't worry.

Comment: I think some of the responses here may ask you to list bounds on $x$, for example $\sum_n x^n$ converges for $-1 < x <1$ and diverges for $x \leq -1$ etc

Comment: basically for S(x,1/2), thats $x+\sqrt 2 x^2+\sqrt 3 x^3 ...$. And as for range, i want it for all real number, of course but x=1 since that's asymptote. It's just interesting to see what plugging in various values of x will give. For example for $S(2,2)=1^2*2+2^2*2^2+3^2*2^3...=-6$, which is pretty cool.

Comment: I understand that from your definition, but you're trying to sum infinite series. Some of those sums may be divergent or convergent depending on the bounds on $x$. I 'm suggesting you list the bounds on $x$ as it will help the responders to find a sum of the series at hand.

Comment: For $|x|<1$ you can express $S$ as [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm)  $S(x,n) = \mathrm{Li}_{-n}(x)$

Comment: @gammatester There we go...

Comment: oo, i see. So the S(x,n) thing was already a thing, thanks for the knowledge. Btw, i'm still not seeing how you can evaluate S(x,1/2) with polylogarithm. Is polylogarithm only defined for integer values of n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you are looking for is [the  polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm)
$$S(x,n)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty i^nx^i=\text{Li}_{-n}(x)$$ which cannot reduce to anything is $n$ is not an integer $\geq -1$.

So, to add to the ones you already have  $$S(x,0)=-\frac{x}{x-1}$$ $$S(x,-1)=-\log (1-x)$$ All other invoke the special function.

Comment: For non-integer $s$ and $|x|<1$ you have $\mathrm{Li}_s(x) = x \, \Phi(x,s,1),$
where $\Phi$ is the [Lerch transcendent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_transcendent)
$$\Phi(z,s,a) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{(a+n)^s}
$$
You have e.g. $S(1/3, 1/2)=\mathrm{Li}_{-1/2}(1/3)\approx 0.593747080583$

Comment: @gammatester. The fascinating Lerch transcendent ! One of my loves !  You can also use Debye functions. Cheers :-)

Comment: wow that got complicated really fast. Is this college level knowledge or in curriculums other than US, the one I'm in, is junior? Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @akirakato. This is just an appetizer ! You will learn a lot about these special functions. They are just fascinating ! You asked a very difficult question and this is good ! Good luck in your studies. Cheers.